# Angular Unit Testing Service with multiple service calls using $q.all

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

Ok here is the scenario we are trying to unit test with Jasmine.  We have a service defined similar to the service below:

```
(function () {

    'use strict';

    angular.module('mymodule')
           .service('myservice', myservice);

    myservice.$inject = ['$q', '$resource', 'progressService', 
            'myservice2', 'myservice3', 'ngDialog'];
    function myservice($q, $resource, progressService, 
            myservice2, myservice3, ngDialog) {

        var self = this;
        self.dataListSvc2 = [];
        self.dataListSvc3 = [];
        self.dataFromResource = null;
        self.myRoutine = myRoutine;

        var myResource = $resource('/someurl/webapi/GetData');

        //TRYING TO TEST THIS ROUTINE!!!
        function myRoutine(param1, param2) {

            return progressService.show($q.all([
                myResource.get({ Param1: param1 }).$promise.then(function (response) {
                    self.dataFromResource = response;
                }),
                myRoutine2(param2),
                myRoutine3(param2)
            ]));

        }

        function myRoutine2(param) {

            return myservice2.getSomeData(param).then(function (response) {
                var results = [];
                self.dataListSvc2 = [];

                response.forEach(function (item) {
                    item.AddField1 = null;
                    item.AddField2 = false;
                    results.push(item);
                });

                self.dataListSvc2 = results;
            });

        }

        function myRoutine3(param) {

            return myservice3.getSomeMoreData(param, [6])
                .then(function (response) {
                    self.dataListSvc3 = response;
                });
        }
     }
})();
```

I am trying to write a unit test for myservice.myRoutine() and not having any luck, I suspect it is due to the $q.all array of promises.  Here is a test I settled on but it is not ideal and honestly I don't feel like it's testing anything of value.  I have also tried "mocking" the three requests with $httpBackend with no luck as all three responses come back in an array with undefined values.  I searched around SO and the web and I am only finding $q.all([]) unit tests referencing controllers but not services.  If anyone has some input it would be much appreciated.  Here is where I settled for the time being:

```
describe('My Service: ', function () {

       var $httpBackend;

        beforeEach(module('mymodule'));

        beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
            // Set up the mock http service responses
            $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
        }));

        it('Can call myroutine from myservice', inject(function (myservice) {

            //Arrange
            var expectedVal1 = 1234;
            var expectedVal2 = 1234;

            spyOn(myservice, "myRoutine");

            //Act
            myservice.myRoutine(expectedVal1, expectedVal2);

            //Assert
            expect(myservice.myRoutine).toHaveBeenCalled();

        }));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`$httpBackend.when('GET', '/someurl/webapi/GetData').respond(data);`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend) to fake the http requests. You should fake the `myservice2.getSomeData` method too and the `myservice3.getSomeMoreData` I guess those methods create http request too so you could fake them in the same manner.

```
expect(myservice.myRoutine).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Is irrelevant as you called it manually ;-).

```
var fixture = {/*some data ... */};

  it('Can call myroutine from myservice', inject(function (myservice) {

        $httpBackend.when('GET', '/someurl/webapi/GetData').respond(fixture);
            //Act
            myservice.myRoutine(expectedVal1, expectedVal2);
            $rootScope.$apply()
            //Assert
            expect(myservice.dataFromResource).toBe(fixture);

        }));
```

Comment: That is the problem I have ran into though.  I did three $httpBackend requests to cover all of the service calls.  However, I did not get back responses I got an array of three undefined items.  I guess having a response is for each is good but is there a way to check/mock a response value?  Ideally the myservice2 and myservice3 calls are completely irrelevant as they are tested on other specs.  If I could just test the myResource.get() I would be happy.

Comment: But you don't have any logic on the myRoutine method. to test, so you don't need to test it. You could test just that `self.dataFromResource` is set. Still you need to call `rootScope.$apply()` for the promisse to be resolve

Comment: The logic on myRoutine that I am interested in is the call to myResource.get().  As I said the other service calls are tested in their own specs.  We need to test that the call to myRoutine is made and would execute successfully like we do for other $httpBackend tests, the data returned is just "mocked".

Comment: Did you see my update? If you mock the data from the `/someurl/webapi/GetData` get response and test that  `myservice.dataFromResource` is actuallythe same data you provided to mock the request then `myResource.get` worked as you expected because the logic in the `success` callback was executed. This is how i would do it.